# Quantiles written as the expectation of a transformation?

Tags: probability, quantiles

Consider a continuous random variable $X$, with finite defined mean $E[X]=\mu$ and variance $E[X^2]=\sigma^2$. Notice that the variance of $X$ can be written as the expectation of a transformed variable $Y_{var}=X^2$.

I'm wondering if there exist similar transformations where the expectation of the transformed variable is a specific quantile of $X$. Specifically: For each $p$, does there exist a transformation $f_p$ such that $E[f_p(X)]=Q_X(p)$, where $Q_X(p)$ is the quantile function of $X$?

I am seeking a transformations of the value of $X$, in the following sense: I realize that one could define a deterministic "random variable" $Y_p=Q_X(p)$, and the expectation would be correct, but I don't consider $Q_X(p)$ to be a "function of X". I'm interested in a transformation $f_p(X)$ where one would be able to take a population of observations $\{x_1,...x_n\}$ from $X$, transform each observation to $\{f_p(x_1),...,f_p(x_n)\}$ and have the mean of these values approach the quantile value $Q_X(p)$.

Comment: "and variance $E[X^2]=\sigma^2$" - That is not the variance, but the second moment.

Comment: Sure: $f_p: X\to X+ Q_X(p) - \mu$ does the trick.  It's exact, too.  I suspect you won't be satisfied with this solution, but if not, then please edit your question to be explicit about what kinds of transformations $f_p$ you seek and what information should be used to determine them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a methodological problem with what you are seeking: you are asking for a *number* (an expected value), to equal a *function* (the quantile function).

Specifically, you seek some

$$f_p(x): E[f_p(x)] = Q_X(p) = x$$
But the "$x$" on the left-hand side will vary over the whole range $S_X$ of $X$,  since, if $g_X(x)$ is the density of $X$ then

$$E[f_p(x)] = \int_{S_X} g_X(x)f_p(x)dx$$

while the "$x$" on the right-hand side is just one value from the range of $X$, determined one-to-one by $p$.

If there is something I have missed in your question, I will be happy to re-work this answer, once I understand what it is.

Comment: Thank you for pinpointing this imprecision. It was an idea that was not fully formed, and I wanted to throw it out there in case it struck someone as mapping cleanly to a literature, but you're right, it doesn't really make sense.